# Remove space between objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

So I made a simple 2D setting where you can move a block.
But I can not completely snap to another sprite (wall).

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Inspector settings wall:**

[image]

**Inspector settings player:**

[image]

PlayerMovement Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public KeyCode moveUp;
    public KeyCode moveDown;
    public KeyCode moveLeft;
    public KeyCode moveRight;

    public float speed = 10f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        Vector2 v = rigidbody2D.velocity;

        if (Input.GetKey (moveUp)) {
            v.y = speed;
            v.x = 0;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
        } else if (Input.GetKey (moveDown)) {
            v.y = speed * -1;
            v.x = 0;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
        } else if (Input.GetKey (moveRight)) {
            v.x = speed;
            v.y = 0;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
        } else if (Input.GetKey (moveLeft)) {
            v.x = speed * -1;
            v.y = 0;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
        } 
        else 
        {
            v.x = 0;
            v.y = 0;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = v;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what can create this space because the this is my first unity game.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure it is because your sprite has this empty border. To fix this make sure that 'player' sprite is fully filled with white pixels or/and your 'wall' sprite. Basicly double check the images.

Also to fix this you could simply make collider slightly smaller to fit the image bounds.

And finally make sure that collider corresponds with pixels you consider a body.

Comment: I double checked and I could not find any empty space. These are my files: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=451ADC2A2ED2D0E7!108&authkey=!AAimm1ss1vE_ZfA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng, https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=451ADC2A2ED2D0E7!109&authkey=!AAxqJwKjBiS2n8A&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: I see, then I was wrong. But you can still play with colliders. But let me know if that is not an option for you. I dont have great experiance in unity2d but I think the solution is in project settings under Physics 2D. With that said try to play with penetration penalty and other settings.

Comment: I am sorry man, but changing the colliders is not an option for me :/